# How do I complete the mission "Eden Prime: Resistance Movement"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

The *From Ashes* DLC has you returning to Eden Prime. While there, I picked up some data about Cerberus troop movements that Liara said would be good to send to the resistance movement.

[image]

Well, I've completed the main mission on Eden Prime and gotten my new crew member, but this quest is still open. I tried flying back to Eden Prime to see if there was something more I need to do there, but it won't let me land.

How do I complete this mission?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pick up three pieces of intel on Eden Prime to complete this mission, it sounds like you only picked up the first one. You can see [this walkthrough on the Mass Effect Wikia](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Eden_Prime:_Resistance_Movement) for the locations of the intel.

I suspect that reloading a save where you're still on Eden Prime or haven't started the mission yet is your only chance to complete it, if you can't visit Eden Prime after finishing the main mission.