# How do you get Freedom Fighter accomplishment in Mass Effect 3?

Tags: mass-effect-3, achievements

I am playing through Mass Effect 3 again now that the Extended Cut DLC has come out, and trying to clean up the few missing achievements I have.

One of the ones I'm missing is `Freedom Fighter` - about delivering the intel about Cerberus to the colonists on Eden Prime.

Looking online, I see there are three pieces of intel to gather when landing on Eden Prime:

- **First**, right in the building where you first land
- **Second**, in the building across the bridge and to the left
- **Third**, kind of down in the back on the left, in a room with a lot of computer monitors

I double checked to make sure I had all three before "finding another way across" back to the stasis pod. Yet, when I got back to the Normandy and checked my accomplishments, it still does not list the `Freedom Fighter` one as complete.

Is there something else I need to do other than just gathering the intel? Do I need to talk to Liara to have her send it as the Shadow Broker, or do something at my console, or does some time need to pass or something, or ?

I saw [How do I complete the mission "Eden Prime: Resistance Movement"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53863/how-do-i-complete-the-mission-eden-prime-resistance-movement), but it is just asking what the mission is (which I know: the three pieces of intel). My question is, after you have the three pieces of intel... then what? Because simply picking them up was not, apparently, enough to trigger the achievement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I complete the mission "Eden Prime: Resistance Movement"?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53863/how-do-i-complete-the-mission-eden-prime-resistance-movement)

Comment: I saw that one (as I have it linked), but don't really think it's a duplicate. He was just asking what the mission is generally. I know what it is though (the three pieces of intel) and am not looking for that information and have done what supposedly completes the mission... but I'm wondering if there's something else to do, or maybe a known bug that it doesn't flag as completed in some instances or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you link to, [How do I complete the mission "Eden Prime: Resistance Movement"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53863/1134), further links to the wiki entry [Eden Prime: Resistance Movement](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Eden_Prime:_Resistance_Movement#Walkthrough) that has a walk-through of how to collect all 3:

> After fighting off the initial wave of Cerberus troops, head into the left structure and you will find another piece of intel in the back room with a bunch of computer terminals. The last piece of intel is located in a building with a number 2 on the outside, and the number 9 painted on the inside multiple times (this is misleading - many buildings have a 2 or 9 written in or on them so to avoid further confusion the building with the last piece of intel is located across from the building with a 2 on it that holds the prothean data), as you move deeper inside you will see a wall on the left side with three consoles, it's the middle one.

That is all you have to do to get the achievement and related War Asset. You should get the Achievement immediately after completely that task/mission.

UPDATE: Per comments, looks like the Op found the answer to his own question. You have to do the above, and not die at all between picking up the three items. (My guess is this is probably a bug and not a requirement, but at least we know now.)

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my question, I know where the three pieces of intel are. I have gathered all three. I double-checked online, to make sure where they all were, and then double-checked in-game to make sure I had gotten them all. What the three pieces of intel are and where they are located is not the issue. I have picked up all three pieces. But then what? Simply picking up the three pieces of intel was apparently not enough to trigger the achievement.

Comment: That is all you have to do. Pickup the 3 pieces. If it's not working, you probably didn't pick up all 3 (there are other things you can salvage for credits, etc.), or you found a bug. Picking up the three items worked for me anyway. You can also confirm if you got all three if you get an in-game e-mail about the colony, and the additional War Asset.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me if I did find an obscure bug... I seem to have a knack for that. I found an obscenely obscure bug in `Force Unleashed` too, back when. Somehow, they seem to be drawn to me.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to have found what MY computer wanted. In order to get the achievement, I had to **not die** at all from one intel to the next. I had to get them all in one run without resuming from death at all. Then I got the achievement. Odd.

Comment: I can provide additional confirmation.  After completing this mission and getting all three pieces of intel on two separate characters, I still had not unlocked the achievement after having completed the mission.  In the second playthrough, I did not die up to the third intel, but I had to reload once because, after a cutscene, Liara was stuck floating in the air.  Noticing that I still did not get the achievement, I restarted the mission, and played through to the third piece of intel without dying or reloading.  I then saved, exited to the main menu, and it finally appeared.